# Syntax error: enum is a reserved word in typescript

Tags: typescript

my project was set up with react-typescript, it can work normally excepted declare with key word "enum".

typescript 3.0 and above
max os

```
enum t {
    code = 'CODE'
}
```

i expected it can compile successfully,but it throw an errow with such a description "Syntax error: enum is a reserved word"

Comment: Please take a look at https://itnext.io/what-do-need-know-about-enumerations-in-typescript-48b554cec43b

Comment: By "set up with react-typescript", do you mean with [create-react-app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app)? Or with [CRA-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/)? And also make sure your file has the `.ts` or `.tsx` extension, and not `.js`

Comment: em, i just set up this project without any cli. but i config my project correctly and it can work with typescript and react , and all my file use the extension .tsx or .ts, whether some plugins necessary for ts  and i didn't install it?

Comment: Your code looks fine, and compiles in the playground. Are you sure there isn't some other context you did not post ? where is the enum defined? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20t%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20code%20%3D%20'CODE'%0D%0A%7D

Comment: I check this syntax in other react project which also setup with typescript, it's OK. It's seem that maybe my config go wrong with something

Comment: i have same issue at now

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge with using the enum keyword.
I created the app using 'npx create-expo-app my-app' without the typescript option.
After entering the piece of code below, I got an error with a description "Syntax error: enum is a reserved word"

```
enum EResult {
  CANCELLED = "CANCELLED",
  DISABLED = "DISABLED",
  ERROR = "ERROR",
  SUCCESS = "SUCCESS",
}
```

To fix the error, I renamed the App.js file to App.tsx
This fixed the error. To reload my app, I installed the typescript dependencies as prompted by the VS Code Editor.
Everything works fine thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue but not with a regular `.ts` file trying to run it in the terminal. The issue was because I wasn't running the file using TypeScript specific Node. After installing the correct package it worked.

Install TypeScript-Node with:

```
npm i -g ts-node
```

run a file with:

```
ts-node <filename.ts>
```